# has_many through and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am a complete rookie in rails development so expect the worst. Up until now I have read a lot about this but I am still unable to find out what I did wrong.

I have difficulties finding the right way to create a model and migration that would enable the relationship described in the model below.

[image: This is what I am trying to accomplish]

Right now this is my migration:

```
    class CreateCoaches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :coaches do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :pupils do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.belongs_to :coach
      t.timestamps
    end

        create_table :talks do |t|
      t.belongs_to :coach

      t.belongs_to :pupil
      t.datetime :talk_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the models:

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :talks
  has_many :pupils, through: :talks
  has_many :pupils
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :talks
  belongs_to :coach
  has_many :coaches, through: :appointments

end

class Talk < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pupil
  belongs_to :coach
end
```

This is the rspec test I am trying to execute (I hope it does not make your eyes bleed...)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Coach do
  before(:each) do
    @coach = Coach.create!(first_name: "Förnamn", last_name: "Efternamn")
  end

  it "creates a Coach" do
    Coach.create!(first_name: "Andy", last_name: "Lindeman")

    expect(Coach.find_by_first_name("Andy").first_name).to eq("Andy")

  end   

  it "creates a Coach and a pupil" do

    @coach.pupils << Pupil.create!(first_name:"Donald", last_name:"Duck")
    expect(@coach.pupils[0].first_name).to eq "Donald"

  end
end
```

And the error:

Failure/Error: @coach.pupils << Pupil.create!(first_name:"Donald", last_name:"Duck")
     LoadError:
       Unable to autoload constant Pupil, expected /home/elgrego/Projects/Coachen/app/models/pupil.rb to define it

Regards 
Elgrego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misspelled your model. You're calling it Patient but I think you meant Pupil. Also, it's better to user t.references rather than belongs_to in your migrations. But it looks like you're doing well so far. You might be making some other errors but I would fix that and see what else is wrong.

Comment: Opps! =) I made that from an example and forgot to edit that. Cheers! It works!

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to freddyrangel's answer.

Modify your models as below:

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pupils
  has_many :talks, through: :pupils
end

class Pupil < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :talks
  belongs_to :coach    
end
```

I would suggest you to read about **[Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)**

Comment: What are the benefit of doing it this way? I see that i would work but Im trying to understand.
I have tried to read up (believe me) but somehow I am having trouble getting it into my own code :-)

Comment: Well. I am not so good at explaining but I could give it a try. Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror